# Ruby regular expression - Extracting part of URL

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a URL like

```
https://endpoint/v1.0/album/id/photo/id/
```

where `endpoint` is a variable.  I want to extract "`/v1.0/album/id/photo/id/`".

How do I extract everything after "endpoint" using a Ruby regular expression?

Comment: Who ever seeing this post, please give a *Regex* solution. Please don't pass by, if you know, how to solve it using *regex*. I am really weak using *regex*. OP needs regex solution.

Comment: The pattern is complex, and is nicely [documented in the RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#appendix-B).

Answer (score 5):

here we go:

```
2.0.0-p451 :001 > require 'uri'
 => true
2.0.0-p451 :002 > URI('https://endpoint/v1.0/album/id/photo/id/').path
 => "/v1.0/album/id/photo/id/"
2.0.0-p451 :003 >
```

Read this [**Basic example**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#module-URI-label-Basic+example).

Comment: @Pavan Happy to hear..Lolz.You are very good in RoR, me not.. *saddy*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . Just curious to know how we can achieve the same using regular expression

Comment: @user1788294 Regex is not my topic. I am poor on it.. :(

Comment: Can somebody help here

Comment: @user1788294 I would recommend this answer over rolling your own regex.

Answer (score 1):

The full regex solution is what the [URI library does in the background](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb#L342-L529). Doing it on your own is largely an exercise in futility...

In any case, a simple regex using named capture groups `(?<name>)` and the `/x` flag on the end to allow whitespace in the formatting.

```
url = 'https://endpoint/v1.0/album/id/photo/id/'

re = /
              ^                    # beginning of string
  (?<scheme>  https?             ) # http or s
              :\/\/                # seperator
  (?<domain>  [[a-zA-Z0-9]\.-]+? ) # many alnum, -'s or .'s
  (?<path>    \/.+               ) # forward slash on is the path
/x

res = url.match re
res[:path] if res
```

This pales in comparison to URI

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex solution:

```
domain = 'endpoint'
link = "https://#{domain}/v1.0/album/id/photo/id/"
path = link.gsub("https://#{domain}", '')
# => "/v1.0/album/id/photo/id/"
```

You can adjust the domain name by changing the "domain" variable.
I used the [String.gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-gsub) function to replace first portion of your link with an empty string (the regular expression part done on line 3 is actually surprisingly simple! It's literally http:// endpoint), which means the path is the only part of the string that will remain.

Answer (score 0):

The URI RFC documents [the pattern used to parse a URL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-B):

```
Appendix B.  Parsing a URI Reference with a Regular Expression

   As the "first-match-wins" algorithm is identical to the "greedy"
   disambiguation method used by POSIX regular expressions, it is
   natural and commonplace to use a regular expression for parsing the
   potential five components of a URI reference.

   The following line is the regular expression for breaking-down a
   well-formed URI reference into its components.



Berners-Lee, et al.         Standards Track                    [Page 50]
 
RFC 3986                   URI Generic Syntax               January 2005


      ^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
       12            3  4          5       6  7        8 9

   The numbers in the second line above are only to assist readability;
   they indicate the reference points for each subexpression (i.e., each
   paired parenthesis).  We refer to the value matched for subexpression
   <n> as $<n>.  For example, matching the above expression to

      http://www.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/uri/#Related

   results in the following subexpression matches:

      $1 = http:
      $2 = http
      $3 = //www.ics.uci.edu
      $4 = www.ics.uci.edu
      $5 = /pub/ietf/uri/
      $6 = <undefined>
      $7 = <undefined>
      $8 = #Related
      $9 = Related

   where <undefined> indicates that the component is not present, as is
   the case for the query component in the above example.  Therefore, we
   can determine the value of the five components as

      scheme    = $2
      authority = $4
      path      = $5
      query     = $7
      fragment  = $9
```

Based on that:

```
URL_REGEX = %r!^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?!
'https://endpoint/v1.0/album/id/photo/id/'.match(URL_REGEX).captures
# => ["https:",
#     "https",
#     "//endpoint",
#     "endpoint",
#     "/v1.0/album/id/photo/id/",
#     nil,
#     nil,
#     nil,
#     nil]

'https://endpoint/v1.0/album/id/photo/id/'.match(URL_REGEX).captures[4]
# => "/v1.0/album/id/photo/id/"
```